# A simple sendfile program, but not works

Tags: c, sendfile

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    int fd1,fd2,rc;
    off_t offset = 0;
    struct stat stat_buf;

    fd1=open("./hello.txt",O_RDONLY); //read only
    fd2=open("../",O_RDWR);           //both read and write
    fstat(fd1, &stat_buf);            //get the size of hello.txt
    printf("file size: %d\n",(int)stat_buf.st_size);
    rc=sendfile (fd2, fd1, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
}
```

So as you have seen, it's quite a simple program. But I just can't find hello.txt in ../
My aim is to see what happens if I put a whatever number, says 10, instead of st_size which may be hundreds of bytes.

Edit:

Thanks for your answers. Well, I followed your advice and changed

```
 fd2=open("../",O_RDWR);
```

to

```
 fd2=open("../hello.txt",O_RDWR);
```

Also, I checked the return value of fstat and sendfile, everything is ok.

But the problem is still the same.

Comment: have you checked that hello.txt is excites in previous folder.?

Comment: Hi @Mr.32 , did you mean exists? Well, the results shows that hello.txt won't be created in the previous folder.

Comment: in previous folder there should be hello.txt which you are going to open..

Comment: well, I've also tried to creat a hello.txt manually or by just using O_RDWR|O_CREAT. So I can find the file there but it's just an empty file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1>

```
  fd1=open("./hello.txt",O_RDONLY); //read only
  fd2=open("../",O_RDWR);           //both read and write
```

replace with

```
 fd1=open("../hello.txt",O_RDONLY); //read only
  fd2=open("../your_file_name",O_RDWR);
```

2>

```
 fstat(fd1, &stat_buf);
```

will fill up some info related to fd1 file in stat_buf . Here size of that file is also return in that structure with  st_size element.

now in

```
 rc=sendfile (fd2, fd1, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
```

total stat_buf.st_size bytes are going to send on fd2 file. if here if you write 10 then only 10 bytes will go in fd2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the filename in the second `open`, not just the directory name.

Please be sure to check the return values of all these functions, including `fstat`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `fd2 = open("../hello.txt",O_RDWR);`?

Comment: Hi @CharlesB, I've followed your advice but the result is still the same